# Use xxhdpi images for xlarge layout

Tags: android, image, layout, scale

I created an Android app with a normal and a large layout.
Now I want to create the xlarge layout, but the images are small, though I have them in all resolutions like l,m,x,xx, and xxx.
Do I have to store them in double size or can I somehow use the existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use images of 1920x1080 resolotion

for Xlarge use this folder `drawable-xlarge-hdpi`

for large use this folder `drawable-large-xhdpi`

for me its working

Answer (score 0):

Size of the images depend on the screen density of the device.

It goes as mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi:xxxhdpi  -> 1x:1.5x:2x:3x:4x

So, check the screen density for the devices and accordingly keep the images in different folders.

You may use same images and just change the layout, but your image may seem pix elated.

If you dont want system to change you images as per density, you can keep them in drawable-nodpi folder.

This link will give you clear idea:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Hope this helps

Comment: I have got a question. where to place dimens.xml for xhdpi and xxhdpi??

Comment: @iOS_Dev .. you can have multiple "values" folders for differnt screen resolution and apprpriately can put dimens.xml in that. For example you can have - values, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, values-sw720dp-land etc

Comment: As sw<N>dp means smallest width and the value (600, 720) defines the width of screen, so you can use "values" folders for phones (xxhdpi is the density) and use "values-sw600dp" and "values-sw720dp" for 7" and 10.1" tablets specifically. Dont get confues between density and screen size.