# Different Layouts for High Resolution Screens?

Tags: android, layout, screen, screen-resolution

I am developing a app which has layout,layout-sw600dp as two layout folders and it works for most of the mobile screens but little distorted in certain mobiles. I tested my app in 3 devices as one with `480*800 px with 4 inches` screen, one with `720 x 1280 px with 5.25 inches`and finally with the awesome Nexus 5 `1080 x 1920 pxw with 4.95 inches`. The layout seemed good for first two mobiles but in Nexus 5, it got totally distorted !! I am placing my icons in `drawable-hdpi,drawable-xlarge-mdpi` and also tried placing certain icons in `drawable-xxhdpi` but no use for Nexus 5. I will here by attach screen shots for reference. I tried asking google for around 3 hours but nothing solid.

**Tried the following :**

1. Added a layout-large but when I choose Nexus 5 in the drop down available in Graphical Layout in Eclipse, it goes back to normal layout which is really weird.
2. Added icons to drawable-xxhdpi but no use.
3. Gone through [this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[image: Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos]

[image]

AS you can clearly see, the layout which fits well in Samsung 5.25 inches screen seems distorted in Nexus 5 4.95 inches. 
Any help on how I should use the layout for high-resolution screens would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have also faced the same issue. when i going to see layout in xxhdpi it will not taking images from that folder. but when actually run your application in your Nexus 5 device it will take images from drawable-xxhdpi.

Comment: And Nexus 5 will not use layout-large folder for layout, it will consider layout folder.

Comment: Ya, I have the exact same issue as you.Any idea on how to rectify it ?

Comment: When you check it in nexus 5 device you will not found this kind of result.

Comment: You mean, it will fit accurately like any other device ? I wouldn't have posted this question if thats the case !!

Answer (score 2):

Please define screen support in your manifest file.

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

if you want to see the effect same for Nexus 5 You can put images in `drawable-large-xhdpi` instead of `drawable-xxhdpi`.

- for Xlarge use this folder drawable-xlarge-hdpi

Comment: So adding this in my manifest would let the layout adjust itself according to different screens ?

Comment: The dimension should be 96*96 and resolution should be 320p and place all those icons in the drawable-large-xhdpi, is that right ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992067/use-xxhdpi-images-for-xlarge-layout i found from here.